# superdev mode not loading module

Tags: gwt, gxt

Hello I'm upgrading my gwt from 2.4.0 to 2.7.0 with gxt 2.3.1a. Everything was looking alright ultil I try to debug the application. I start the debug using superdev mode without any problems aparently. Here is the end of my debug start.

"

```
[INFO]          Unification traversed 108163 fields and methods and 8186 types. 8146 are considered part of the current module and 8146 had all of their fields and methods traversed.
[INFO]          Compiling 1 permutation
[INFO]             Compiling permutation 0...
[INFO]             Linking per-type JS with 8130 new types.
[INFO]                prelink JS size = 26317582
[INFO]                prelink sourcemap = 26317582 bytes and 534648 lines
[INFO]                postlink JS size = 26027857
[INFO]                postlink sourcemap = 26027857 bytes and 528723 lines
[INFO]             Source Maps Enabled
[INFO]          Compile of permutations succeeded
[INFO]          Compilation succeeded -- 128,510s
[INFO]       Linking into C:\Users\ALEXAN~1.RIS\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-3435183735990420589.tmp\br.com.webb.ria.Application\compile-2\war\br.com.webb.ria.Application; Writing extras to C:\Users\ALEXAN~1.RIS\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-3435183735990420589.tmp\br.com.webb.ria.Application\compile-2\extras\br.com.webb.ria.Application
[INFO]          Link succeeded
[INFO]          Linking succeeded -- 11,742s
[INFO]       147,211s total -- Compile completed
```

"

After I start the remote debug I get the normal gray window of gwt debug plugin. Everything is processed without any errors. When I copy the generated link on my browser I get the following message.

"Compiling br.com.webb.ria.Application" My gwt module.

The problem is that after the message vanishes I get nothing but the plain html. The module is not loaded on screen and I can't see my application.

I've tried using the "Dev Mode On" button from my bookmark, nothing happens. I tried to stop using "Dev Mode Off" and then clicking on "Dev Mode On" again, nothing happens.
I also tried enabling https support and `<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />`. Nothing seems to help. Any ideas?

Comment: Bookmarks should not have produced any effect with 2.7 as far as I understand it. What's the source code of that plain html? Is there a trace of your module's top level panel?

Comment: No trace at all, the module does not shoe at all. I also tried to downgrade to gwt version 2.6.1 and the same thing happens when I lanch superdev mode, but it works ok when turn it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike convencional debug mode, superdev mode requires a full compilation before debuging to work. If you are using maven and face the same problem, perform a mvn clean package before trying to debug.